# What differences are between ""multiprocessor" and "parallel processors"?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, parallel-processing, multi-processor

I was wondering what differences are between ""multiprocessor" and "parallel processors", in general?

I saw them in Stallings' Computer Organization and Architecture (see the screenshots below). The book says:

> Computer organizations can be distinguished by the presence of one or more control units. Multiple control units imply multiple processors. Following our previous discussion, if the multiple processors can function cooperatively on a given task, they are termed **parallel processors**.

If a multiprocessor is in contrast to parallel processors, is a multiprocessor multiple processors which don't cooperate on a task?

I have another guess based on an impression probably from seeing something similar somewhere.
Do the processors in a multiprocessor share the same main memory? If parallel processors are in contrast to a multiprocessor, do parallel processors don't share the same main memory but have distributed memory?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*is a multiprocessor multiple processors which don't cooperate on a task?*" - Yes, but more likely, completely *unrelated* & independent processes/programs would be executed.

Comment: @sawdust  Thanks. Do the processors in a multiprocessor share the same main memory? Do the processors in parallel processors have separate (distributed) main memories? Could you give an example for a multiprocessor, and an example for parallel processors?

Comment: There are no hard definitions. Anything is possible. You haven't even considered separate instruction and data memories (aka Harvard architecture). How broad is the definition of "*multiprocessor*"? Does a GPU count as a "processor"? Note that Linux kernel has built-in support for *symmetric* multiprocessors (aka SMP).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunate terminology, indeed.

Strictly speaking, (a) *vector processing* means executing exactly the same operation at any given time (SIMD, e.g. a matrix/vector multiplication - hence multiple ALUs), (b) *parallel* processing (MIMD) means doing roughly the *same work*, but on different data parts (e.g. image tiles) and possibly with slightly different paths of execution, while (c) *concurrent* processing (="multiprocessor") means just doing parts of the same problem (e.g. saving an image and concurrently loading the next one to be processed)... or even doing unrelated tasks.

Of course, there is cooperation in both (b) and (c), but on a different level. It's a matter of granularity.

I believe in this interpretation, "parallel" processors would require some synchronization features (e.g. for data distribution and maybe a "wait" instruction).

When it comes to memory access, there may or may not be shared memory, or a combination of local and shared memory.

- In general, an entity writing to a shared memory address and another entity reading from the same address will require some kind of synchronisation - both low-level in hardware (bus arbitration) and high-level in flow control (did processor A already write the information which is needed by B?).
- In addition, local caching might be rendered worse-than-useless. Cache is usually organised in *cache lines* (consecutive memory cells, e.g. 4096 bytes), and a cache line is considered to be invalid if *bus snooping* detects a write access to anywhere in the memory area cached. Imagine processor A writing bytes to odd, and B to even addresses. Bernstein's conditions are not violated (the write sets do not coincide), but both processors will nevertheless invalidate their local caches frequently.

For those reasons, with growing number of processors and - in regard to general algorithms - shared memory does become more and more impractical. A solution might be using processor-local (exclusive) memory and explicit communication channels between processors, cf. *transputer* architectures. This solves both memory access and synchronisation problems, but requires different algorithms (allocation, data distribution, message passing).

Comment: Thanks. Do the processors in a multiprocessor share the same main memory? Do the processors in parallel processors have separate (distributed) main memories? Could you give an example for a multiprocessor, and an example for parallel processors?